# Mudar rota de autenticação usuário do laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com um problema, no meu sistema fiz uma função na HomeController para carregar configurações de ambiente do usuário(Rota /home).
Porem se caso usuário deixar o Auth expirar em outra rota(Não ser /home), o laravel vai redirecionar para login e após autenticar ele voltara o usuário para rota que foi expirada, causado o erro pois as variáveis de ambiente não foi carregada no HomeController(/home).
Minha duvida, tem alguma forma de eu setar para **TODAS** as vezes que usuário foi autenticado(login) ele ser direcionado **APENAS** para a roda /home? Se possível isso iria carregar as configurações todas as vezes que o Auth expirar.

Oque precisa ser carregado (HomeController):

```
        $userconfig = DB::table('userconfigs')
                        ->select('*')
                        ->where('idUser', Auth::user()->id) 
                        ->get();

        $userconfig = $userconfig[0];
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['flagMenuProdutos'] = $userconfig->flagMenuProdutos;
        $_SESSION['flagMenuServico'] = $userconfig->flagMenuServico;
        $_SESSION['flagMenuVenda'] = $userconfig->flagMenuVenda;
        $_SESSION['flagMenuEstabelecimentos'] = $userconfig->flagMenuEstabelecimentos;
        $_SESSION['flagMenuUsuario'] = $userconfig->flagMenuUsuario;
        $_SESSION['flagMenuPessoas'] = $userconfig->flagMenuPessoas;
        $_SESSION['flagMenuCotacao'] = $userconfig->flagMenuCotacao;
        $_SESSION['flagMenuEstoque'] = $userconfig->flagMenuEstoque;
        $_SESSION['flagMenuParceiros'] = $userconfig->flagMenuParceiros;
        $_SESSION['flagMenuClientes'] = $userconfig->flagMenuClientes;
        $_SESSION['flagMenuAgenda'] = $userconfig->flagMenuAgenda;
        $_SESSION['flagMenuFinanceiro'] = $userconfig->flagMenuFinanceiro;
        $_SESSION['flagMenuNotaFiscais'] = $userconfig->flagMenuNotaFiscais;
```

Minha duvida, tem alguma forma de eu setar para **TODAS** as vezes que usuário foi autenticado(login) ele ser direcionado **APENAS** para a roda /home? Se possível isso iria carregar as configurações todas as vezes que o Auth expirar, ou alguma forma de contornar esse problema, pois esses dados são usados em varias partes nas blades.

Estou usando o método de Autenticação padrão do Laravel(Auth).

Answer (score -2):

Se você der uma olhada no arquivo `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`, por exemplo, encontrará o seguinte código:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Você pode ver que uma variável `$redirectTo` existe e tem o valor de `/home` para onde os usuários são redirecionados após o login.

No sistema de autenticação integrado do Laravel, você pode personalizar muitos lados, como a rota de redirecionamento, usando a variável `$redirectTo` que existe nos controladores de login e registro.

Se você deseja redirecionar seus usuários para rotas diferentes das padrão após o registro ou login, basta alterar o valor de `$redirectTo`.

---

Agora uma outra alternativa que você pode seguir é, pega esse load de informações que se encontra na `HomeController` e coloque ela dentro de algum `Middleware` e coloque ele para carregar apenas em rotas que o usuário está logado. Assim independente da página que seu usuário estiver ele irá carregas as informações sem precisar passar pela `/home`

Comment: Eu já tinha testado essa possibilidade, porem não eficiente. 
Então a alternativa foi fazer um events para identificar o login e carregar uma função em listeners para carregamento das session.